# Get Raspberry PI 3 voltage

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I have warning under-voltage, how I can detect it remote (bash script, python)?
I tried read value from pin 35, but I always get similar value (1), nevertheless   on swap power supply.

Comment: Are you willing to add circuitry or do you have to do it with just what's native to the Pi?

Comment: Only native Pi.

Answer (score 1):

`vcgencmd get_throttled`

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=147781&start=50#p972790 for interpretation of get_throttled

Comment: Thnx, and how I can get current voltage value? Because `vcgencmd measure_volts` always output 1.2V.

Comment: That has NOTHING to do with supply voltage. You can't get supply voltage, because the Pi has no analog circuitry.